# Can anyone help me understand, How the below code works?

Tags: python

Part of code that I do not understand, how it work?

```
data_folders = [os.path.join(root, d) for d in sorted(os.listdir(root))
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, d))]
```

Here is the link for the code:
https://github.com/rndbrtrnd/udacity-deep-learning/blob/master/1_notmnist.ipynb

Screenshot for the entire code:
[image]

Question:
"os.path.join(root, d)" joins the path and folder name (d) which is coming from the for loop, one at a time. But I do not understand what is the use of "if" condition which is doing the same thing? (I guess)

Comment: It's just building a list of sorted directory names

Comment: Please post all code as text. Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @the23Effect the term is "list comprehension"

Comment: @the23Effect It's a called a *list comprehension*, there's also a generator expression with `( )` around it.

Comment: "But I do not understand what is the use of "if" condition which is doing the same thing? (I guess)" It's not. it checks if the path created by `os.path.join` is a directory.

Comment: @KlausD. My bad initially the code did not show the square brackets and I saw the whole code later and forgot to change generator to comprehension.

Comment: @KlausD. I wanted to highlight the part of the code that I did not understand and make it easy to observe, hence the image. I have also given the link to the entire code in the post. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list comprehension syntax. The internal part is actually a generator but the square bracket makes it as a list comprehension.

It contains three parts, and last part is optional.

```
output_list = [
    generate something                  # Part 1: this will be the output content.
    from some iterable                  # Part 2: this is where you pick elements from.
    which matches a condition           # Part 3: this is the optional condition to match.
]
```

So for your question this is how it should be read,

```
data_folders = [
    os.path.join(root, d)                       # Part 1: generate this.
    for d in sorted(os.listdir(root))           # Part 2: from these.
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, d))     # Part 3: if they meet this condition.
]
```

Comment: This is an awesome explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I read it like this:

Join path and folder name which is coming from the `for` loop one at a time, **if the joined path and folder name is a directory**. If not, just skip the said path.

The purpose of the code is to build a **list of sorted directories.**